# Generic coroutines Action parameter

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a GET/Post request function that takes in generic parameter and this is my get method:

```
public static IEnumerator Get<T>(Action<T> callback, string url)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        callback(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))
            callback(www.downloadHandler.text);
    }

}
```

This is how I use it:

```
public void GetTest()
{
    string url = "***";

    StartCoroutine(Http.Get<String>((response) => {
        if (response != null)
            Debug.Log(response);
    }, url));
}
```

But this line:

```
callback(www.error);
```

Throws the error that it cannot convert a string to T

That makes sense to me but I don't know how to solve this, this is what I have tried

```
callback((T)www.error);

callback(www.error as T);
```

Comment: In `Http.Get` method both of the `if` and `else` is passing a `string` to callback so why are you receiving an `Action<T>` instead of `Action<string>` in the method signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just call the callback directly since it's a generic. Use `Convert.ChangeType` to convert the `www.error` or `www.downloadHandler.text` to `Object` then cast it to `T` and finally invoke the callback `Action` and pass that `T` to it.

```
public static IEnumerator Get<T>(Action<T> callback, string url)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        T t = (T)Convert.ChangeType(www.error, typeof(T));
        callback(t);
    }
    else
    {
        T t = (T)Convert.ChangeType(www.downloadHandler.text, typeof(T));
        callback(t);
    }
}
```

---

While this should work and should solve your compile issues, I see no need to do this. It's totally unnecessary to use generics here. Just using `string` or `byte` array to return the result.

Comment: I use this becuase if i want to get a texture i need to return a texture

Comment: Sure but you can overload that function to handle that. I say this because of boxing and unboxing happening when `Convert.ChangeType` is used but it's up to you to make that decision. Anyways, I don't know why you put your an answer with what's in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the string to T

This is my solution:
callback((T)Convert.ChangeType(www.error, typeof(T)));